Creating ROS2 node in visual studio C++ compilation problem. rclcpp problem
I am trying to build my first ROS2 node in C++. I followed all steps in python and successfuly created my first node in py, but when I try to create it in C++ using Visual studio, VS doesn't compile the following header file :
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp" the code itself
.json file when I tried to change the directory 
The error
I tried to change the directory as shown in the second photo and rebuild again but the problem stays.

Check https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors and [mcve] please!

what are those ** mean in path name? doesn't look like a valid path to me.

Make sure you installed the API SDK and that it is accessible at the path relative to the source file (since you are using quotes on the include). If not, you can add an include directory to your project settings that the .hpp file is relative to, and use angle brackets instead:
#include <rclcpp/rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp>

